# Android: Avoid duplicate entry when supporting both ACTION_GET_CONTENT and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider, storage-access-framework

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html states:

```
ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is not intended to be a replacement for ACTION_GET_CONTENT.
The one you should use depends on the needs of your app:

Use ACTION_GET_CONTENT if you want your app to simply read/import data.
With this approach, the app imports a copy of the data, such as an image file.
Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT if you want your app to have long term, persistent access
to documents owned by a document provider. An example would be a
photo-editing app that lets users edit images stored in a document provider.
```

This indicates that most apps that provides files should support both intent types.

But when an app supports both `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` (by having an activity matching that in its intent filter) and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` (by implementing a document provider), it is shown twice when e.g. attaching a a file to Gmail. This is due to the file picking UI showing both document providers and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` matchers (the latter being shown further down below a divider).

Is it possible to avoid this duplicate showing of an app to avoid confusing users?

See the below screenshot and the Box entry showing up twice for an example of the problem:

[image: Screenshot showing duplicate entry in the Open from dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From slightly farther down on that same page in the [Supporting devices running Android 4.3 and lower section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#43):

> The `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` intent is only available on devices running Android 4.4 and higher. If you want your application to support `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to accommodate devices that are running Android 4.3 and lower, you should disable the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent filter in your manifest for devices running Android 4.4 or higher. A document provider and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` should be considered mutually exclusive. If you support both of them simultaneously, your app will appear twice in the system picker UI, offering two different ways of accessing your stored data. This would be confusing for users.

The section you refer to is on the *client* side - apps connecting to your `DocumentsProvider` can use both `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, so you no longer need the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent-filter or activity at all on Android 4.4 and higher devices.

They suggest creating `bool` resources based on version code (i.e., in `values-v19`) that would allow you to change the `android:enabled` value in the Manifest, disabling or enabling components based on Android version.

Comment: Thanks, missed that! I see now that "ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is not intended to be a replacement for ACTION_GET_CONTENT" is in the context of a client app - for a provider app however that is the case.